Caddy for https on top of working django asgi app supposedly breaks websocket communication
I have a working django asgi application that uses channels for websocket communication with daphne and redis, and is running in a dockerized setup. To enable the secure https protocol, I tried going for a solution using caddy with selfsigned certificates (the app is deployed to a server internal to my organization).
I get the caddy setup working so that I can access via https, but it seems to break the websocket part. For example, on clicking some buttons that should trigger websocket communication, I get errors like
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'ws' before initialization
with a pointer to where I do a ws.send(...) in javascript. The websocket is initialized with
let ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/validation/');

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  mywebapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      ssh:
        - default
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 mywebapp.asgi:application
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"   
      - "8443:443" 
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile 
      - /selfsigned.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.crt
      - /selfsigned.key:/etc/ssl/private/selfsigned.key
    depends_on:
      - mywebapp
volumes:
      caddy_data:

And this is my Caddyfile:
example.com {
    tls /etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.crt /etc/ssl/private/selfsigned.key
    reverse_proxy mywebapp:8080 {
        header_up Host {host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
        header_up Connection {>Connection}
        header_up Upgrade {>Upgrade}
    }
}

I'm happy to provide more context if needed, I am currently very unsure what the issue could be, and I have little experience with the tools. My app was working before adding the caddy service in docker-compose.yml and the Caddyfile; the only other change I did was adding this to my settings.py:
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://example.com:8443'
]


I have not found a solution - but switched to nginx as a reverse proxy in the meantime, which worked.
